# How to create folders and images using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filesystems

I have an AngularJS app that, upon requested to upload an image, creates a folder inside the file system (CentOS) and then puts that image there, telling the user everything went OK or not.

Is this possible? All I've found is ways to download the file.

Thanks.

Comment: File system on the local machine or on a remote server?

Comment: It is local in respect to the Angular app, serving from /var/www/html/appFiles
So I just need to create a folder hierarchy starting from /appFiles

Answer (score 0):

It is better to delegate this task to a service on the server, since it is file that is uploading to a server. I put simple rest service to file upload this file to the server.